# Specify a jar matching a pattern for Ant's java task?

Tags: java, ant, jar, build

I've got a jar file that will match a certain pattern, but contains a version number that will change over time (it's placed there using a dependency manager). It is the only jar file that will ever be in that directory. Is there a way I can invoke Ant's `java` task using the directory and (if necessary) a pattern to find the jar file rather than statically specifying the filename? I'd rather not have to update build.xml every time the version changes.

So given something like this:

```
/path/to/some/jarfile-3.24.8.jar
```

... that might later look like this:

```
/path/to/some/jarfile-4.3.2.jar
```

Can I achieve the equivalent of this?

```
<java jar="path/to/some/jarfile-*.jar" fork="true" spawn="true" />
```

---

**Thoughts**

I was thinking maybe I could rig something up using the `fileset` task, but I couldn't find a way to reference it from the java task (and the java task doesn't support the `<include>` nested tag like some other tasks do).

... after further research, `pathconvert` looks like it might help. I'm not familiar enough with the mechanics to see how to piece things together though.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found a solution using `fileset` and `pathconvert` - here's my simplified solution:

```
<fileset dir="/path/to/some" id="jarfile-path-contents" includes="jarfile-*.jar" />
<pathconvert property="file.jarfile" refid="jarfile-path-contents" />
<java jar="${file.jarfile}" fork="true" spawn="false" />
```

1. I used `fileset` in order to specify the pattern and location of the jar.
2. I used `pathconvert` to place the found jar file reference into a property.
3. Then I was able to simply reference that property in my `java` task.